# Comments not showing after using comment_form in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am using comment_form() in Wordpress, and the comment form is showing up, but the actual comments that have been approved are not:

Here is the code I have

```
<?php 
    $comments_args = array(
    // remove "Text or HTML to be displayed after the set of comment fields"
    'comment_notes_after' => 'Note: Comments are moderated so will not publish immediately.',
    // change "Leave a Reply" to "Comment"
    'title_reply'=>'What did you think of this story? Please share a comment.', 

    // change the post comment button
    'label_submit'      => __( 'Submit your comment' ),
                );

    comment_form($comments_args);

?>
```

I have unchecked and checked the right options under Settings -> Discussion

Do I need another call apart from comment_form?
Does it make a difference that this is a custom post type?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried `wp_list_comments` to list comments for the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make any difference if it is a custom post type but you should declare comment support for your custom post type in function.php where you have written arguments for custom post type. e.g. `'supports'  => array( 'title' ,'author','comments')`.

And Use like this in single-post-type.php write `<?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>` to call comments.php.
And in take your comments.php as backup and replace it with the following -

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments
 *
 * The area of the page that contains both current comments
 * and the comment form. The actual display of comments is
 * handled by a callback to twentytwelve_comment() which is
 * located in the functions.php file.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */

/*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and
 * the visitor has not yet entered the password we will
 * return early without loading the comments.
 */
if ( post_password_required() )
    return;
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php // You can start editing here -- including this comment! ?>

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
        <h2 class="comments-title">
            <?php
                printf( _n( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'twentytwelve' ),
                    number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), '<span>' . get_the_title() . '</span>' );
            ?>
        </h2>

        <ol class="commentlist">
            <?php wp_list_comments( array( 'callback' => 'twentytwelve_comment', 'style' => 'ol' ) ); ?>
        </ol><!-- .commentlist -->

        <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // are there comments to navigate through ?>
        <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="navigation" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="assistive-text section-heading"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?></div>
        </nav>
        <?php endif; // check for comment navigation ?>

        <?php
        /* If there are no comments and comments are closed, let's leave a note.
         * But we only want the note on posts and pages that had comments in the first place.
         */
        if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() ) : ?>
        <p class="nocomments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.' , 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php //comment_form(); ?>
    <?php if ('open' == $post->comment_status) : ?> 
    <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">       
        <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title"><?php comment_form_title( 'Leave a Reply', 'Leave a Reply to %s' ); ?></h3>
        <div id="cancel-comment-reply">
        <p class="small"><?php cancel_comment_reply_link( __("Cancel Reply", "bonestheme") ); ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="cancel-comment-reply">
            <?php cancel_comment_reply_link(); ?>
        </div>       
        <?php if ( get_option('comment_registration') && !$user_ID ) : ?>
        <p>You must be <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-login.php?redirect_to=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink()); ?>">logged in</a> to post a comment.</p>
        <?php else : ?>

            <form action="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-comments-post.php" method="post" id="commentform">

                <?php if ( $user_ID ) : ?>

                    <p>Logged in as <a href="<?php echo get_option('siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/profile.php"><?php echo $user_identity; ?></a>. <a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(get_permalink()); ?>" title="Log out of this account">Log out &raquo;</a></p>

                    <?php else : ?>
                    <p class="comment-notes">Your email address will not be published. Required fields are marked <span class="required">*</span></p>

                    <p class="comment-form-author"><label for="author">Name <?php if ($req) echo '<span class="required">*</span>'; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="author" id="author" value="<?php //echo $comment_author; ?>" size="22" tabindex="1" /></p>

                    <p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">Mail <?php if ($req) echo '<span class="required">*</span>'; ?></label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php //echo $comment_author_email; ?>" size="22" tabindex="2" /></p>

                    <p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">Website</label>
                    <input type="text" name="url" id="url" value="<?php echo $comment_author_url; ?>" size="22" tabindex="3" /></p>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <!--<p class="form-allowed-tags"><small><strong>XHTML:</strong> You can use these tags: <code><?php echo allowed_tags(); ?></code></small></p>-->

                    <p class="comment-form-comment"><p><label for="comment">Comment <?php if ($req) echo '<span class="required">*</span>'; ?></label>
                    <textarea name="comment" id="comment" cols="100%" rows="10" tabindex="4"></textarea></p>

                    <p class="form-submit"><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="5" value="Post Comment" />
                    <?php comment_id_fields(); ?>
                    </p>
                    <?php do_action('comment_form', $post->ID); ?>           
            </form>      
        <?php endif; // If registration required and not logged in ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; // if you delete this the sky will fall on your head ?>



</div><!-- #comments .comments-area -->
```

Note- Please change class name and id as per your css

Comment: Thanks Nishant. I already have comments support in there:                        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'post-formats', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields' ), so I think the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Nishant. It worked when I called comments_template, so I created my own version of comments.php and specified it in the call:      comments_template( '/story_comments.php', true ); In there I was able to style the comment_form call the way I wanted. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the comments.php file from the twentyfourteen theme. If it works, it is likely that nishant is right with comments probably not being activated for your post type.
TwentyFourteen’s comments.php is also a good example on best practise for comments. You might check it against your other code, if there is some.